# Get date from FullCalendar and send it to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, datetime, fullcalendar

I have this code in fullCalendar click event:

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view){
    if (view.name === "agendaDay") {
        window.location.assign('targetpage.php?date='+ date);
    }
}
```

The received date in target page seems like a timestamp (like this: 1483457400000).

I tried this in the target page:

```
$date = $_GET["date"];
$dateStr = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
```

But it didn't seem to work.

Any idea how can I convert selected datetime in fullCalendar to a valid php date string?

Comment: $date = $_GET['date'] / 1000;

Comment: Wow that's right! I can't believe I spent the whole evening on this! BTW, it's giving me the time one hour difference, does it have to do with timezone? and you know how to fix it?

Comment: Just add or subtract 3600 from $date. You might also want to consider checking what PHP's default timezone is.

Comment: I can do that, but I need to understand why is that happening?

Comment: I guess that makes sense. Great man, thanks!

Comment: I did write an answer. Lol.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice it was you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of some of them zeros.

```
$date = $_GET['date'] / 1000;
```

Maybe even

```
$date = floor($_GET['date'] / 1000);
```

Timestamps are usually always in GMT+0 and modified by PHP's date function to match PHP's default timezone. For example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Comment: Thanks I got that, now when I click on a time slot, it's giving me time plus one hours. Does it have to do with this conversion?

Comment: Probably more likely to be a timezone issue